# take out margins on DataGridTextColumn in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Currenty I have a `DataGrid` like so

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ResultSet}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        SelectedItem="{Binding AValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
        CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectionMode="Single" MinHeight="300">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ViewDetailsCommand}"/>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource AResource}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Header="{l:LocText SomeText}" Binding="{Binding ABinding1}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Header="{l:LocText SomeText1}" Binding="{Binding ABinding2}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Header="{l:LocText SomeText2}" Binding="{Binding ABinding3}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Header="{l:LocText SomeText3}" Binding="{Binding ABinding4, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Header="{l:LocText SomeText4}" Binding="{Binding ABinding5, StringFormat='{}{0:c}'}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is the style of the Column Header:

```
<Style x:Key="AResource" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1c313a" />
</Style>
```

The thing is, each column has like some `Margin`, a left and right one so I can't put the columns almost together, I want to eliminate that `Margin` or whatever it is.

**EDIT:**

[image]

This is the image, As you can see If I put the Column2 "Close" to Column1, then there is this sort of content that takes out the space of Column1, each column has this space.

Comment: maybe, it is `Padding`? try `<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />` in Column Header style

Comment: Yes, I did tried that just a couple of seconds ago, I even took out that style (Commented it) to no avail.

Comment: quick glance over templates shows [two Thumbs](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/58730fd31abc7213ddcaa8503185cad17a705139/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.DataGrid.xaml#L228) which are [wide enough](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/2740f14a814896d42032ae0013b765a8a0ec04c3/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Thumb.xaml#L27)

Comment: What do you advice to change in order to make the width of those thumbs to 0? Im new to xaml.